# how to load a null-terminated string from program mem and push into the stack?

Tags: assembly, stack, avr

I'm trying to learn assembly, AVR in particular, can anyone tell me how to load a null-terminated string from program mem and push into the stack? And how to write out the reversed string into data memory? Many thanks

I know how to load and stuff but I'm still lost

Comment: Where did you get stuck? Also you don't need the stack for that.

Comment: haven't know where to start and also the question asked me to pushes it onto the stack. Thanks

Comment: You said you knew how to load ... so start by loading a byte. Then check if it's zero. Push onto stack if not. Repeat.

Comment: ok I got it, but I don't know to write out the reversed string into data memory, I'm totally have no idea,

Comment: Once you know the length, loop one pointer backwards and the other forwards, loading+storing.  No need to copy to the stack.

Comment: See http://www.avr-asm-tutorial.net/avr_en/beginner/addressing/addressing_flash.html#45

Answer (score 0):

If we assume the address of the null terminated string is labeled `STR_ADDR`, we can do something like this:

```
LDI ZL, LOW(STR_ADDR << 1)
LDI ZH, HIGH(STR_ADDR << 1)    // LOAD A PROGRAM MEMORY ADDRESS INTO Z POINTER

LPM R16, Z+                    // LOAD DATA BYTE FROM PROGRAM MEMORY
PUSH R16                       // PUSH IT ONTO THE STACK
CPI R16, '\0'                  // CHECK IF DATA BYTE IS THE NULL TERMINATOR
BRNE PC-3                      // IF NOT -> START NEXT ITERATION
                               // ELSE CONTINUE PROGRAM EXECUTION
```

Note that the above code will only work if no further changes are made to the stack as long as the data is still needed on the stack. For example if you try to wrap this code as a function - you will have to account for the fact that the `RET`,`RCALL`, `CALL` instructions modify the stack when they are called.

To write out a null terminated string from the stack to memory in reverse (assuming your memory address is `SRAM_ADDR`, and that the stack pointer is the same as when the previous code was run - i.e at the memory address of the '\0' + 1):

```
LDI ZL, LOW(SRAM_ADDR)
LDI ZH, HIGH(SRAM_ADDR)

POP R16                        // LOAD THE DATA BYTE FROM THE STACK
ST Z+, R16                     // STORE THE DATA BYTE TO SRAM
CPI R16, '\0'                  // CHECK IF DATA BYTE IS THE NULL TERMINATOR
BRNE PC-3                      // IF NOT -> START NEXT ITERATION
```

***Important note***
This above solution might not work if you are using anything other than the atmel AVR assembler. If you use GCC/GNU AVR compiler or some other compiler, then the conventions are a tad different as those compilers have slightly different parsers with different conventions.